# Get next result with specific ORDER BY satisfying the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given a TripID I need to grab the next result that satistfies certain criteria (TripSource <> 1 AND HasLot = 1) but I've found the problem that the order to consider "the next Trip" has to be "ORDER BY TripDate, TripOrder". So I mean that TripID has nothing to do with the order.

*(I'm using SQL Server 2008, so I can't use LEAD or LAG but I'm also interested in answers using them.)*

### Example datasource:

```
    +--------+-------------------------+-----------+------------+--------+
    | TripID | TripDate                | TripOrder | TripSource | HasLot |
    +--------+-------------------------+-----------+------------+--------+
 1. | 37172  | 2019-08-01 00:00:00.000 |     0     |      1     |    0   |
 2. | 37211  | 2019-08-01 00:00:00.000 |     1     |      1     |    0   |
 3. | 37198  | 2019-08-01 00:00:00.000 |     2     |      2     |    1   |
 4. | 37213  | 2019-08-01 00:00:00.000 |     3     |      1     |    0   |
 5. | 37245  | 2019-08-02 00:00:00.000 |     0     |      1     |    0   |
 6. | 37279  | 2019-08-02 00:00:00.000 |     1     |      1     |    0   |
 7. | 37275  | 2019-08-02 00:00:00.000 |     2     |      1     |    0   |
 8. | 37264  | 2019-08-02 00:00:00.000 |     3     |      2     |    0   |
 9. | 37336  | 2019-08-03 00:00:00.000 |     0     |      1     |    1   |
10. | 37320  | 2019-08-05 00:00:00.000 |     0     |      1     |    0   |
11. | 37354  | 2019-08-05 00:00:00.000 |     1     |      1     |    0   |
12. | 37329  | 2019-08-05 00:00:00.000 |     2     |      1     |    0   |
13. | 37373  | 2019-08-06 00:00:00.000 |     0     |      1     |    0   |
14. | 37419  | 2019-08-06 00:00:00.000 |     1     |      1     |    0   |
15. | 37421  | 2019-08-06 00:00:00.000 |     2     |      1     |    0   |
16. | 37414  | 2019-08-06 00:00:00.000 |     3     |      1     |    1   |
17. | 37459  | 2019-08-07 00:00:00.000 |     0     |      2     |    1   |
18. | 37467  | 2019-08-07 00:00:00.000 |     1     |      1     |    0   |
19. | 37463  | 2019-08-07 00:00:00.000 |     2     |      1     |    0   |
20. | 37461  | 2019-08-07 00:00:00.000 |     3     |      0     |    0   |
    +--------+-------------------------+-----------+------------+--------+
```

### Results I need:

Given TripID `37211 (Row  2.)` I need to get `37198 (Row  3.)`
Given TripID `37198 (Row  3.)` I need to get `37459 (Row 17.)`
Given TripID `37459 (Row 17.)` I need to get `null`
Given TripID `37463 (Row 19.)` I need to get `null`

Comment: Would you please provide your sql scrtip?

Comment: I wish it would go without saying... but please, please, please encourage your organisation to upgrade from an outdated, unsupported version of SQL Server.

Comment: @Fmanin: I don't know if you want this `SELECT * FROM Trips ORDER BY TripDate, TripOrder;`. Or if you want my tries, I have not achieved it.

Comment: @gvee I will try it...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery or `outer apply`:

```
select t.*, t2.tripid
from trips t outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from trips t2
      where t2.tripsource <> 1 and t2.haslot = 1 and
            (t2.tripdate > t.tripdate or
             t2.tripdate = t.tripdate and t2.triporder > t.triporder
            )
      order by t2.tripdate desc, t2.triporder desc
     ) t2;
```

Comment: One problem is that *the order have to be based on 2 values*:
1st: TripDate and 2nd: TripOrder

Comment: @sergidb . . . I adjusted the logic.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff I think that it's the nearest option I've seen at the moment. 
But, how can I specify "the next trip following TripId 37336" for example. I've explained?